# Expected value with multiple conditions

Tags: independence, covariance-matrix, conditional-expectation

I'm trying to handle a case where I have:

E[X|Y,Z] where I know X is dependent on both Y and Z, but Y and Z are independent of each other. I see a [different post at this link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/93780/conditional-expectation-with-conditioning-on-two-independent-variables) which states it is not true that E[X|Y,Z] = E[X|Y]E[X|Z], but the counter example is the case in which X is independent of Y and Z.

In my case, since I KNOW X is never independent of Y and Z, is it true that E[X|Y,Z] = E[X|Y]E[X|Z]?

I am asking because I want to calculate E[X|Y,Z] as

E[J|K] = μJ+Σ(JK)Σ(JJ)^-1(K−μK)

Using the covariance matrix which I know. I don't know how to handle this without first breaking up the conditions.

Comment: Notice that $$E[X|Y,Z]=\sum_x xP[X=x|Y,Z]$$ and that $$E[X|Y]E[X|Z]=\left(\sum_x xP[X=x|Y]\right)\left(\sum_x xP[X=x|Z]\right),$$ which will lead to a number of quadratic terms of possible values of $X$.

Comment: Hm I see. Do you have an alternative method you could recommend?

Comment: I mean, the first expression will be a weighted sum of the $x$, the second will be a weighted sum of the $x^2$, so they should not be equal in general.

Comment: So it would be the sum then? E[X|Y] + E[X|Z]

Comment: Why should it be?